# Is there a way to change stlyes position:'relative' to position:'absolute' depending on Y scroll value in a Animated.ScrollView React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I have an animated header that gets smaller and opacity increments when the scroll view is being scrolled down.. Under that there is a filter bar that needs to stick just below the animated header after it has fully clamped. I got it to do just that with `position:"absolute"` and making that view follow the y value. The problem is that it seems **LAGGY** when the animated header has not fully clamped yet, and when it is scrolled up it looks much worse. On top of that the scroll indicator gets hidden behind the position:'absolute' filter bar view... I think the solution would be to have that view with position relative then change it to absolute.. but I need to know if there is a way to change the style `position:"relative"` to `position:"absolute"` after it gets done clamping so it can look smooth until it clamps, or atleast a way to do this without it looking laggy, any help is very apreciated. 
some code here (some tags may not be closed but you get the gist):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.scrollY = new Reanimated.Value(0);
  }

render() {
    const translateY = multiply(min(this.scrollY, 0),-1);
    const headerHeight = this.scrollY.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT - HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
        outputRange: [HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT, HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
        extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP
    });

this.NewHeaderHeight= this.scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT],
    outputRange: [0, HEADER_MIN_HEIGHT + 1],
    extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP
});

const headerOpacity = this.scrollY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE / 3, HEADER_SCROLL_DISTANCE],
    outputRange: [0, 0, 1],
    extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP
});

return(<View style={{flex:1}}>
        {/* contenido */}
         <Reanimated.ScrollView 
            style={[{flex:1}]}
            bounces={false} 
            scrollEventThrottle={16}  
            onScroll={Reanimated.event([
            { nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scrollY } } }
            ])}
        >
            {/* Start of animated HEADER */}
            <View style={{height: HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT, width:'100%'}}>

                {/* IMAGEN DEL HEADER Y ICONS*/}
                <ImageBackground style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center' }} source={{uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-etc}}>

                //THERE WOULD BE SOME ICON AND OTHER CONTENT HERE DOESNT MATTER THOUGH
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
*//there would be more children here doesnt matter either since filter toolbar is position:absolute for the moment*
 </Reanimated.ScrollView>

{/*THIS IS FILTERBAR (here is where want to change the position style depending on scroll value)*/}
<Reanimated.View
                style={[styles.categoryContainer, styles.shadow,  { transform: [{translateY}],position: 'absolute', top: headerHeight, elevation:1, backgroundColor:'white'}]}
            >
                 <FlatList 
                    horizontal
                    data={infoDataFilter}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    renderItem={({item}) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity 
                            key={item.id}
                            style={[styles.categoryItem]}
                            activeOpacity={.7}
                            onPress={() =>  console.log(item.screen)}
                        >
                            <Text style={{paddingVertical: 5, fontSize:12, fontWeight:'bold', color: '#444444'}} >
                                {item.name.toUpperCase()}
                            </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                />
</Reanimated.View>
```

that does this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GdnkUEdmko

It scrolls perfectly when that view has position:'relative' and i would like to have it like that but change to position:'absolute' when the animated header has clamped..

EDIT: i am using react native version .61.5
reanimated ^1.7.0, gesture-handler ^1.6.0, react navigation x4 libraries.
this was tested on android samsung galaxy s6 devmode (its the same on production)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think changing the `position` prop is a good idea. To fix the "laggy" behavior, you can use `useNativeDriver` on your `Animated.event` and move the animation over to native side. It usually does wonders. Here's how you do that:

`Reanimated.event(
  [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.scrollY } } }],
  { useNativeDriver: true })`

Although, you have to make sure you don't drive any layout animations (width, height, etc) with `scrollY` or you'll get an error, since those are not supported.

**EDIT**

I noticed you ARE using scrollY to drive a layout animation (`headerHeight`). To make layout animations smooth, you have to use `LayoutAnimation`. It's a very good library. Here's a [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation).